# Transfer one digit to one cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to transfer one digit of a number into one cell from one workbook to another.

Example:

```
Worksheet 1: 1,234.56
Worksheet 2: A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
             1   2   3   4   5   6
```

These are the formulas I've been using but the last formula for the last digit isn't correct.

A1 Formula: This works

```
=IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>9999999.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,7,1),
    IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>999999.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,6,1),
       IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>99999.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,5,1),
          IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>9999.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,4,1),
             IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>999.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,3,1),
                IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>99.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,2,1),
                   IF('Worksheet 1'!D7>9.99,MID('Worksheet 1'!D7,1,1),"")))))))
```

A6 cell: This does not work:

```
=IF(MID(RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7,2),1,1)=".",MID(RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7,2),1,1),
    IF(MID(RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7,2),1,2)=".",RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7,1),"0"))
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from your very complex formula, you are trying to return the leftmost digit. If so, all you need is `=LEFT('Worksheet 1'!D7)`: the number is automatically converted into a left-justified string. Or if it's the last digit you're after, `=LEFT(MOD('Worksheet 1'!D7,10))`.

Comment: Thanks AFH! The formula =LEFT(MOD('Write Payment Ticket'!$D$7,10)) only works sometimes. If I enter the formula in S14 in Worksheet 2, and Worksheet 1 D7 has 0.01, Worksheet 2, S14 has "0" and does not show the 1. Similarly, if I change Worksheet D7 = 0.00, Worksheet 2, S14 = blank cell. Any suggestions. Otherwise, this formula is pretty awesome. I inherited this worksheet from someone else who couldn't figure out how to get last digit to show up in worksheet 2, S14.  I've tried several ways but haven't had success.

Comment: @Cmpmd2, as I've mentioned in my answer from below, I have no idea how these formulas can work.  They seem completely broken or way over the top for what you need.  You've only given us the formulas for A1 and A6.  Give us the remaining formulas (A2 to A5) so we can get an idea about what is going on here.  To fix A6, all you really need is `=IF(MID(RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7,3),1,1)=".",MID(RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7,3),3,1),"")`, though I'd rather do anything than use such offensive formulas.  These formulas are not generic so don't expect them to work anywhere.

Comment: @Cmpmd2 - I was having to guess which digit you want: my formulae give you the first and last digits of the integer part. If you want the absolutely final digit, whether there are decimals or not, then it's `=RIGHT('Worksheet 1'!D7)`. Please clarify which digit you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand why you have such a massive if-else formula, and how you use it in each cell (A1, A2, etc.).

So, why not use a simpler formula for each digit you want to strip out?

Something like the following should work for you:

For each cell in the SAME column, starting at ROW 1, use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(MOD('Worksheet 1'!$D$7,POWER(10,9-ROW()))/POWER(10,9-ROW()-1))
```

i.e. it's the same formula for all cells in the same column, therefore, you can just fill-down.

**Some explanation:**

`POWER(10,9-ROW())` is calculating a divisor, based on powers of 10.

The power `9-ROW()` will give 8, 7, 6, 5, ..., as you go down the column, IF you start at row 1 of course.

Therefore, as you go down the column, you divide by successively smaller powers of 10, to extract the digit at that decimal position.

..

To start at a different row than 1, or to extract digits starting at positions other than in the 10,000,000s, just change the `9` so that X`-ROW()` gives you the first power of ten you want to start at.

..

Note also, instead of "`LEFT`" in the above, you could use "`ROUNDDOWN`" to zero decimal places (i.e. something like this `ROUNDDOWN(MOD.../POWER..., 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the formula Jehad! I'm really unfamiliar with this formula. It a really good explanation.  I actually want to start the digits on Worksheet 2, K14 - S14.   If worksheet 1, D7 = 7.05, I need Worksheet 2, Q14 = 7 R14 = 0 and S14 = 5.  K14 thru P14 need to be blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: This formula will not work if you're intention is to go **across** columns, rather than **down** a column (your question states A1, A2, ..., A6, which is down a single column).  It'll be easier if you show us fully what you currently have, what result you want to achieve, and your current problem, so we can give you a single clear answer.